# Spotify with NextAuth doesn't return profile picture

Tags: javascript, next.js, spotify, next-auth

I'm using NextAuth v4 and after authenticating with Spotify, I don't have access to the user's profile picture. Here's the information I get from Spotify:

```json
{
  name: '***',
  email: '***',
  sub: '***',
  accessToken: '***',
  refreshToken: '***',
  username: '***',
  accessTokenExpires: ***,
  iat: ***,
  exp: ***,
  jti: '***'
}
```

And here's my code in `/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`:

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next'
import SpotifyProvider from 'next-auth/providers/spotify'
import spotifyApi, { LOGIN_URL } from '../../../lib/spotify'

async function refreshAccessToken(token) {
  try {
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(token.accessToken)
    spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(token.refreshToken)

    const { body: refreshedToken } = await spotifyApi.refreshAccessToken()
    console.log(`REFRESH TOKEN IS: ${refreshedToken}...`)

    return {
      ...token,
      accessToken: refreshedToken.access_token,
      accessTokenExpires: Date.now + refreshedToken.expires_in + 1000, // = 1 hour as 3600 returns from spotify API
      refreshToken: refreshedToken.refresh_token ?? token.refreshToken, // = the refresh token it never ends whether the company doesn't modify it or stop it=
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)

    return {
      ...token,
      error: 'RefreshAccessTokenError',
    }
  }
}

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers (step 1)
  providers: [
    SpotifyProvider({
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: LOGIN_URL,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
      // initial sign in
      if (account && user) {
        return {
          ...token,
          accessToken: account.access_token,
          refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
          username: account.providerAccountId,
          // we are handling expiry times in Miliseconds hence * 1000
          accessTokenExpires: account.expires_at * 1000,
        }
      }

      // refresh token
      // Return previous token if the access has not expired yet
      if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires) {
        console.log('EXISTING ACCESS TOKEN IS VALID')
        return token
      }

      // Access token has expired, so we have to refresh it...
      console.log('ACCESS TOKEN HAS EXPIRED, REFRESHING...')
      return await refreshAccessToken(token)
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.accessToken = token.accessToken
      session.user.refreshToken = token.refreshToken
      session.user.username = token.username

      console.log('Async session callback', token)

      return session
    },
  },
})
```

Do I need to do anything to get the user's profile picture, or does Spotify not return it? I've done some research and couldn't find this issue anywhere.

Thanks,
DillonB07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you need a profile picture to be able to get the image!

If you don't have a profile picture, Spotify just returns `null`.